# Removing space generated by box of multiline sum subscript

Tags: math-mode, equations, mathtools, vertical-spacing

I have the following equation

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{\mathclap{\substack{T_i \in \\
\{T_1,T_2, T_4,\\
T_5,T_6,T_7\}}}} T_i W^i_\mu &\equiv T_{+}W^+_\mu + T_{-}W^-_\mu +\\
&+  T^\prime_{+}V^+_\mu + T^\prime_{-}V^-_\mu +\\
&+T_{++}U^{++}_\mu + T_{--}U^{--}_\mu. 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

which generates

[image]

What is the best way to obtain the same result but without the spacing between first and second line generated by the sum limits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you encase the material to the left of `\equiv` in a `\smash[b]{...}` directive.

[image]

Observe that I've also inserted `{}` particles ("empty math atoms") at the ends of rows 1 and 2 in order to inform TeX that the preceding `+` symbols are binary rather than unary operators.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\smash[b]{\sum_{\mathclap{\substack{T_i \in \\
                \{T_1,T_2, T_4, \\ T_5,T_6,T_7\} }}} 
T^{}_i W^i_{\mu} }
&\equiv  T^{}_{+}W^+_{\mu} + T^{}_{-}W^-_{\mu} + {} \\
&\quad + T'_{+}V^+_{\mu}   + T'_{-}V^-_{\mu}   + {} \\
&\quad + T^{}_{++}U^{++}_{\mu} + T^{}_{--}U^{--}_{\mu}\,. 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just a quick question: if I move the alignment character & in the first line to the right of the `\equiv`, the rest of the line gets glued to the equiv line. What is happening?

Comment: @GaloisFan - The correct syntax is `&=`, `&\equiv`, etc. If, for some reason, you insist on writing `\equiv&`, you really ought to write `{}\equiv` to help TeX figure out the proper spacing amounts.

Comment: why is it wrong in the case I want the spot *after* the `\equiv` to be aligned with the other reference points?

Comment: perhaps I have always misunderstood how `\split` and general alignment environments work!

Comment: @GaloisFan - It's wrong because you have to go out of your way to get the correct spacing. Put differently: Why write `{}\equiv&` instead of `&\equiv`?

Comment: because I want `\equiv` to be to the left of the alignment spot, not to the right.

Comment: @GaloisFan - You can choose to conform to the recommended syntax for where to place the `&` alignment markers, insist on using your own syntax and find that, surprise, "the rest of the line gets glued to the equiv line" (as you put it quite eloquently earlier today), or keep using your own syntax but make adjustments -- mainly by adding well-placed but otherwise useless empty math atoms -- to undo the-line-gets-glued-to-the-equiv-line problem that's entirely of your own making. Your call. I don't know you, I don't care what you do.

Comment: wow... I'm not saying or implying that you are wrong, do not know what you are talking about or that I have a better approach. I'm just stating my objective and trying to understand how what you are teaching me accomplishes it: I do not want to align by the beggining of the line, but rather by an arbitrary point in the middle of it. I'm sure you had understood that (or that my poor english prevented it) and are precisely solving my inquiry -- I just did not understand how and was stating my confusion.

Comment: @GaloisFan - Take 2 separate `align` setups: First, `\begin{align} 1+1 &= 2 \end{align}`; second, `\begin{align} 1+1 =& 2 \end{align}`. If you typeset both, you'll find that the whitespace around the `=` symbol is normal, i.e., perfectly symmetric, in case 1. In contrast, the whitespace distribution is highly asymmetric in case 2; indeed, case 2 just looks wrong. In order to 'fix' case 2, it turns out that what's needed is `\begin{align} 1+1 {}={}& 2 \end{align}`. Happily, the fixed version is now identical to case 1. Put differently, your earlier justification for using the poor (continued)

Comment: @GaloisFan -- (continued) syntax -- "because I want `=` to be to the left of the alignment spot, not to the right" -- turns out to be illusory: the outcomes of `1+1 &= 2` and `1+1 {}={}& 2` are the same. Placing `=` (or `\equiv`) to the left or right of `&` makes no difference in terms of *output*. In terms of *input*, of course, `1+1 &= 2` is a whole lot simpler than `1+1 {}={}& 2`. That's a good enough justification, for me at least, to go with the recommended syntax. What you choose to do in the end is, as I wrote before, entirely up to you.

Comment: The example you provide features a single line and does not replicate the behaviour I wish to achieve or compare. Consider `\begin{align} a&=b+c \\ &+d \end{align}` compared to `\begin{align} a=&b+c \\ &+d \end{align}`. The result I wished for is accomplished by the second instance, except for the suppressed spacing to the right of the equal sign. That is what I meant stating that the result was different and that what I intended to obtain was alignment with the spot to the right of the equal sign as basepoint.

Comment: I understand that leaving the alignment character to the left of the equal sign and conforming to manually inserting a `\quad` in the second line to get the desired format may be the prefered practice -- and have not contested it at any moment. What is astounding to me is your unbelievably rude reaction to a stranger (as you brilliantly pointed out that I am, to paraphrase you) interacting with you as politely as I was.

Comment: @GaloisFan - I'm sorry to have been perceived as being rude.